# Is there a way to hide the white page shown when focus on search bar in xamarin forms app

Tags: forms, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuvot.jpg)When I press to write text on the xamarin forms searchbar  a page shown with keyboard and editor and button that fill the full width of screen but I nerd the basic page to show with keyboard on the button like chat or any other search engine I attach the page shown when press to typing on landscape mode

I try softinput. Resize but no doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This related to the Android version.

I tested search bar on the Android 7.0 it will open the page show with keyboard and editor and button that fill the full width of screen. But on the Android 13 it will not happen.